# Windows Network Load Balancing Manger & IIS original source IP?

Tags: iis, load-balancing

I have Microsoft NLB on front of three IIS-servers. Which are configured on the same cluster.

NLB itself is doing fine, but on IIS-logs all the requests are coming from the NLB:s IP-Address. Is there a way to pass the original source IP to the IIS when using the NLB?

Comment: Which version of Windows are the IIS servers running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helps if I add client-ip address on the IIS-logging settings enabled.